# What effect will changing the LED connection / polarity have on the ADC work and load?

Tags: led, adc, current-source

In the current circuit, the LEDs indicate the state on the ADC pins. Unfortunately, it is inconsistent (inverted) with what I have on the outputs of IC7. I would like to change it as simply as possible. The solution may be to change the position of the LEDs - then the ADC will not sink current, but the source current. The question is, if I do not exceed 1-2mA per pin, the ADC operation will not be disturbed and not overloaded. Datasheet says Isource / Output Source Current / design limt = -6mA.
[image]

Comment: So where is the problem? The datasheet says it's kosher and changing to sourcing is probably going to be beneficial to your adc noise as you're not pulling current through the 0V pin. Nevertheless, it was a bad design decision to run loads on the adc data bus. You need some uA709 opamps to get some retro cred though.

Comment: @Kartman Thank you. The circuit is tested and works well. The problem is these LEDs - when I write the 8-bit words with a potentiometer, ADC into the SRAM - LEDs show inverted state. So I'm looking for the simplest possible way to make it not inverted. Adding some op-amps expands the number of parts though. Is it a real issue to source current for LEDs in that design?

Comment: The suggestion of opamps was a joke - your design was valid over 40 years ago so i suggested adding some very old opamps to make it more retro.